# Why is it possible to pass an array instead of a selector?

Tags: jquery

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

$(arr).each(function() { alert(this) });
```

This works OK with jQuery except the set isn't made up of DOM elements but integers. Shouldn't this be not allowed?

Comment: Why wouldn't it not be allowed?

Comment: Why? No animal was hurt in the processing of this array of integer with jQuery

Comment: Have you checked the manual? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: I don't know, ask the jQuery people... it's their design decision. I agree though that as per documentation it does not look like this should work.

Comment: Or in case you think this is a bug, you can report it, but this is not the place to discuss this.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I think its a type error. Functions like the one above usually expect 'this' to be a DOM element but in the case above its an integer. Thus '$(this).html()' for example would cause an error and it would be an easy error to make.

Answer (score 1):

As Felix Kling says it's their decision.

`$(arr).each()` is allowed but you shouldn't use it as it is considered to be less efficient than `$.each()`.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/each/#comment-40044794

Also read this one: http://api.jquery.com/each/#comment-38585086

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery` function (which is equivalent to `$`) return a **regular array** of jQuery objects.

So it makes perfect sense that you snippet works, since it's just a regular array.

If you do as [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2011/11-more-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) says and look at the source, you'll see that it uses basically the same code for

```
$.each(array, function(index, value) {});
```

which handles regular arrays and objects.

Basically, it doesn't care what's *in* the array for it to work, it just iterates through an array.

That being said, for clarity, you should probably use the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) variation because it's faster (more direct) and so someone can quickly see it's a "regular" array of "plain" values and not jQuery objects.

Semantics matter, people.

Comment: `jQuery` does not actually not return an array, it returns an *array-like* object.

Comment: Ok, I was eating pie while writing this, and it totally doesn't make sense that it is a regular array. I knew that. My bad. Dang pie.